# How do I convert an integer to a list and vice versa in Oz?

Tags: oz, mozart

How do I convert an integer to a list and back in [Oz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oz_programming_language)? I need to take a number like `321` and reverse it into `123`.

The Reverse function in Oz only works on lists so I want to convert 321 to [3 2 1], reverse it, and convert [1 2 3] back to 123. Can this be done in Oz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disclaimer: I didn't actually know Oz until 5 minutes ago and only read the examples at Wikipedia, so the following may be riddled with errors. It should however give you a good idea on how to approach the problem. (Making the function tail-recursive is left as an exercise to the reader).

Update: The following version is tested and works.

```
local
  % turns 123 into [3,2,1]
  fun {Listify N}
    if N == 0 then nil
    else (N mod 10) | {Listify (N div 10)}
    end
  end

  % turns [1,2,3] into 321
  fun {Unlistify L}
    case
      L of nil then 0
      [] H|T then H + 10 * {Unlistify T}
    end
  end
in
  % Turns 123 into 321
  {Browse {Unlistify {Reverse {Listify 123}}}}
end
```

Comment: Very clever. I actually figured out how to reverse the digits of the number mathematically using mod and div and so no longer need to convert the numbers to a list in order to Reverse them. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick more succintly:

```
{Show {StringToInt {Reverse {IntToString 123}}}}
```

Cheers